# ARKit - Yaw of device to the world origin?

Tags: rotation, scenekit, arkit

I need to know exactly where the device is, including its angle / rotation Y, in the world origin (of ARKit). I can get the node pointOfView or main camera, get their transform, rotation, eulerAngle… but don’t know how to convert them to the yaw / rotation Y (note that the device can look up / down thus rotation.y is not the right answer for me). Thanks